# VSTO ClickOnce application trying to update via Visual Studio local file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vsto, clickonce

I've built a VSTO add-in for Microsoft Word and deployed to a webserver.  Installation goes off without a hitch.  When I create an updated version of the application and redeploy it to the webserver, the add-in correctly detects that there's a new version and attempts to update it.  This is where I'm running into the following error (the "xxx" indicates that I had to censor something):

```
There was an error during installation
Name: 
From: file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/xxx/xxx/bin/Debug/xxx.vsto

The customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed 
and cannot be upgraded from this location. To install this version of the customization, 
first use Add or Remove Programs to uninstall this program: xxx. Then install the new
customization from the following location: 
file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/xxx/xxx/bin/Debug/xxx.vsto
```

This appears to me as if I left a local reference of some sort in my Project, but I can't find anything of the sort.  The only reference to this file is within the xxx.vbproj.FileListAbsolute.txt file that's generated in the bin/Debug folder.

Not sure if this is also a clue, but I'm seeing Registry Keys added referencing this as the location of the VSTO Project Manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being no issue with ClickOnce; there appears to have been a conflict because I had first built this as a ClickOnce, then my masters asked me to also do a regular MSI install package so they could see the difference.  As soon as I removed the regular installer code, all became very happy again.  So, if you run into this issue, you may have made the same mistake I just did.